# Trouble Implementing custom lock screen (background activities issue)

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

Im building a custom home screen with a custom lockscreen.

When the screen turn off, I launch the lock screen (activity),
However, when the lock screen is killed (by "finish()"), it goes back to
the last activity in my homescreen apk, and not to the real activity (apk) that
was visible right before the screen went off.

For example, if i'm in Calculator application, or in Clock applicaiton, And the lock screen turns on, When the lock screen activity is finished, It doesn't return to Calculator/Clock

Here's where I register the lock screen (in the main launcher activity) for receiving screen on/off events:

```
private void doLockScreenOperations()
{
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();

    IntentFilter lockfiFilter = new IntentFilter();
    lockfiFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    lockfiFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new LockScreenReceiver(), lockfiFilter);
}
```

Here's the receiver itself, where I launch the lock screen's activity:

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
        {
            if (LockScreenActivity.isLockScreenAlive == false)
            {
                Intent lockIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
                lockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(lockIntent);
            }
        }

        else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The LockScreenActivity is, at that moment, a simple activity with a button
that is called finish() when the button is clicked.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure mate, but you have to consider this:
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK starts a fresh new group of views 
so logically you don't have a previous activity to go back to when exiting your lock screen.

I'm building one myself, very similarly to how you do it actually.
but unfortunately having these problems:
-it loads to slow sometimes
-it loads whenever it "feels" like :/
nm, goodluck mate

Comment: How do you solve the Home button problem? do you (both) have some repo to share?